# My streamlit programs goes blacked out as soon as I enter a query

Tags: python, streamlit

Guys i have been trying to develop a chatbot using streamlit  the problem is it goes blacked out whenever i enter a query
as shown in the pictures
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhaSC.png)
and here's the pic after it excuted
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8OSl.png)
please tell me how to solve this blacking out problem

```
#everything is imported above..
if "messages" not in st.session_state.keys(): # Initialize the chat message history
    st.session_state.messages = [
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "Hello how are you?"}
    ]

# 3.3. Load and index data
if prompt := st.chat_input("Enter a message✍"): # Prompt for user input and save to chat history
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})

for message in st.session_state.messages: # Display the prior chat messages
    with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
        st.write(message["content"])

if st.session_state.messages[-1]["role"] != "assistant":
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        with st.spinner("Thinking..."):
            prompt=prompt.lower()
            if 'uwu' in prompt:
                print('ahem')
                response='hahaha'
            elif 'your name' in prompt:
                response="You can call me Alvin"
                

            elif 'hello' in prompt:
                response='hello'
                                        
             
              
                  
                  
                 
            
            else:
              emoji=random.choice(random_emoji_list)
              re = Reply(prompt)
              response=re+emoji
            st.write(response)
            message = {"role": "assistant", "content": response}
            st.session_state.messages.append(message)
```

Comment: Can you share a runnable code snippet? `random_emoji_list` is not defined